# Contract expander on losing focus

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles, expander

I need the expander to expand whenever a cell gets focus.

Beside from that I want the expander to contract whenever the cell loses focus.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Expander VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
                  IsExpanded="{Binding Path=IsFocused,
                                       Mode=OneWay,
                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                            Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType=DataGridCell},
                  UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
        <!--Expander.Content-->
        </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGirdTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

This solution is only expanding but not contracting.

Where am I wrong ?

**Notes:**

```
DataGrid.SelectionMode="Single"
DataGrid.SelectionUnit="Cell"
```

Comment: Where do you click to get LostFocus, do you click another cell?

Comment: Yap, thats just it

Comment: @Milan might be .. the problem is, that `IsFocused` is readonly so I cannot use anything other that `OneWay`

Comment: does my edited code seem viable to you? IsFocused is readonly, yes, but even if you bind to a property with a setter too, the problem is still here. oneway binding leads to this, but you cannot use a twoway binding in your snippet above

Comment: @Milan it seems to work. It's only workin on the first colum for some reason but i guess theres an error on my side ../

Comment: the snippet you posted is only 1 column, you gotta attach this behavior to every expander that you use. perhaps use DataGrid.CellStyle to set this, rather than only that one column template DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate

Comment: @Milan that's just what I did ... still does not seem to work

Comment: can user also close the expander manually? or should it simply go away only after the row is unselected?

Comment: I'd like to have both. Not that selectionunit is cell not row!

Comment: added a modified expander in my post, i believe this might do what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "This solution is only expanding but not contracting."

click on your expander to expand it once, and then try to click somewhere else in your datagridcell, it will not work, the binding is destroyed the first time you expand manually and the expander will not expand automatically when datagridcell IsFocused is true anymore. same happens if you use oneway binding on a simple bool property in viewmodel.

EDIT:

try using this expander, i believe it might do just what you need:

.xaml

```
<local:MyExpander DataGridCellToObserve="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}}" >
```

.cs

```
public class MyExpander : Expander
{
    public MyExpander()
    {
        this.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    public DataGridCell DataGridCellToObserve
    {
        get { return (DataGridCell)GetValue(DataGridCellToObserveProperty); }    
        set { SetValue(DataGridCellToObserveProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataGridCellToObserveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataGridCellToObserve", typeof(DataGridCell), typeof(MyExpander), new PropertyMetadata(test));

    private static void test(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (e.NewValue as DataGridCell).Selected += (d as MyExpander).setExpanded;
        (e.NewValue as DataGridCell).Unselected += (d as MyExpander).setExpandedFalse;
    }

    private void setExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, true);
        this.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    void setExpandedFalse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, false);
        this.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution isn't clean. You will add event handler each time the property changed and at the end it will slow down the control. There should be more logic to add event handler once.

Comment: but the property is set only once the MyExpander is instantiated in xaml, right? anyways, im sure the OP is capable of cleaning up as needed. editing is also welcome ;b

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with fewer dependencies (if you aren't already using Blend Behaviors):

```
<Expander Header="Hello" Content="Goodbye">
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard TargetProperty="IsExpanded">
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0" />
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard TargetProperty="IsExpanded">
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0" />
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Style>
</Expander>
```

Comment: clicking the expander manually does not close it. also, selecting a cell doesnt mean that the expander gets focus, so it is not expanded automatically when the user selects a cell